# npm ERR! could not determine executable to run

Tags: node.js, npm

I wanna run my project by `npm run watch` and when I do nothing, it suddenly appears an error like this.

```
git:(master) ✗ npm run watch

> watch
> npx mix watch

npm ERR! could not determine executable to run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/bintangtobing/.npm/_logs/2021-06-04T08_11_16_499Z-debug.log
```

Does anyone know about these errors?

I have already did a solution,
it is

> delete node_modules on the project folder and run an `npm install` and it still got the same error.

Can anyone help me, please?
Thank you, everyone.

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? I'm stuck too. If you could add an answer that would be very helpful.

Comment: I had to upgrade laravel-mix from 5 to 6 to fix this.

Comment: For those who get this error using Mikro-ORM: make sure you install mikro-orm cli `npm install --save @mikro-orm/cli`

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Ended up doing

```
rm -rf .git/hooks
npm install
```

Followin this sugestion https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/1845#issuecomment-814884999

Worked for me

Comment: `rm -rf .git/hooks` worked like a charm!

Comment: Important is to use npm i. pnpm not working for that.

Answer (score 36):

It worked for me:

```
npm uninstall husky && npm install --save-dev husky@4
```

It happens because git is trying to find a file that doesn't exist (in version 5) so downgrading helps, I know that's not the best solution but could help someone.

Or try to migrate husky (4 to 7):

https://github.com/typicode/husky-4-to-7

Comment: For me, `npm install` did it. I already had husky@4

Comment: Reason why this works is that husky versions after 4 stopped installing git hooks automatically. They put up instructions how to add those here https://github.com/typicode/husky

Comment: for me it worked without uninstalling husky - so it may be safer this way

Answer (score 14):

My issue was is that I was mistakenly calling `npx start` instead of `npm start`.

I was doing this from the `CMD` line in my `Dockerfile`.

I realize this isn't the OPs question, but the error and title may bring others here who are getting this error.

Comment: This is exactly what my issue was. Thank you for posting this.

Answer (score 10):

`npm install`

I had this problem after trying to debug a build issue. **I deleted the node_modules** and ran the app in a docker container. But this meant the husky npm package wasn't available locally anymore so a simple `npm install` fixed the problem

Answer (score 8):

In my case i was using wrong cmd .
**npx create react-app assignment**

cmd should be like
**npx create-react-app my-project**

mistake : I was missing "-" in between create and react in cmd

Answer (score 7):

I had to downgrade node from v17.0.1 to v14.18.1, because newer node-version was not supported by one of my project's dependencies.

( e.g. via "nvm use 14", see [Node Version Manager](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) )

Comment: happened to me with firebase-tools. Had to downgrade node from v16 to v14

Answer (score 6):

It worked for me:

```
git commit -m "updating the dependency packages" --no-verify
```

Sometimes its due to pre-commit hooks

Answer (score 4):

I had tried installing npm in a repo that didn't need it, and the installation had failed, therefore

```
rm -rf .git/hooks
```

*without* using

```
npm install
```

worked for me (because `npm install` would fail again).

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was using `npm build`.

It worked after changing to `npm run build`.

Answer (score 2):

I was stuck on this error for a while. Very obvious, but I was simply running an invalid npx command.
The message by itself wasn't very helpful and it took me quite some time to figure that out :'(

Answer (score 1):

`npm audit` fixed the issue for me while trying to run,
`npx ng n <folder-name>`.

Angular was installed locally in this folder, which
already contained an Angular project.

Answer (score 1):

The error found after installing cypress; opening cypress with the path works fine :

```
./node_modules/.bin/cypress open
```

Answer (score 1):

You can install globally the [eas-cli package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eas-cli) and the command should work.

Install it with npm:

```
npm install -g eas-cli
```

Install it with yarn:

```
yarn global add eas-cli
```

Comment: This is the same issue with `babel-cli`, for whatever reason it can't be run via `npx`.

Answer (score 0):

`npx react-native run-android` npm ERR! couldn't determine execution to run this helped me to run

```
 npm i yarn
 yarn install
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with Expo using node 16, fixed by using node 18.

=> `nvm use 18`

Maybe not a proper solution, but it un-blocked me..

Answer (score -1):

just use `npm install`
then -> `npm start`

Answer (score -1):

terminal was .zsh, my problem was fixed when I changed it to .bash

Comment: This isn't related.