# When running the React project Got error as npm ERR?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

***I could not run my react project. When I entered npx start I am facing this problem Can anyone please Help me.***

npm ERR! could not determine executable to run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\ateyu\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-05-26T19_30_57_752Z-debug-0.log

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "web",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.5.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.0.6",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.1",
    "dayjs": "^1.10.7",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-reveal": "^1.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-star-rating-input": "^8.0.1",
    "react-stars": "^2.2.5",
    "react-table": "^7.7.0",
    "simple-react-lightbox": "^3.6.9-0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your `package.json` file and the *exact* command you are attempting to use? Oops, you are using `npx start`? Try `npm start` instead to run your React project.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67833794/npm-err-could-not-determine-executable-to-run),This could be the soulution to your problem.

Comment: Did using `npm start` resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Delete package-lock.json file and Node module then re run npm install . Then run npm start.