# Error npm ERR! could not determine executable to run

Tags: error-handling, sequelize.js

I was trying to run the command "npx sequelize db:create" in my VSCode and ran into the error "npm ERR! could not determine executable to run". I tried various methods such as deleting my node modules then npm install, "rm -rf .git/hooks
npm install" method, etc but it does not work.

Comment: Duplicate [npm ERR! could not determine executable to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67833794/npm-err-could-not-determine-executable-to-run)

Comment: I tried all those method in there and it still does not work

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue but in a CD pipeline. Instead of using `npx sequelize` use `npx sequelize-cli`:

```
npx sequelize-cli db:create

npx sequelize-cli db:migrate
```