# 'npm ERR! could not determine executable to run' in OpenShift pod

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, openshift

I am trying to deploy an Angular app to OpenShift and below is a copy of my package.json

```
{
  "name": "app-admin",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "scripts": {
    "global": "npm install",
    "start": "npx ng serve",
    "build": "npx ng build",
    "watch": "npx ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "npx ng test",
    "e2e": "npx ng e2e",
    "cypress:open": "cypress open",
    "cypress:run": "cypress run"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.2.0",
    "drag-on-drop": "^3.6.1",
    "npm": "^9.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.6",
    "@angular/cli": "~14.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.2.0",
    "@cypress/schematic": "^2.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "axe-core": "^4.4.3",
    "cypress": "^10.10.0",
    "cypress-axe": "^1.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.3.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.2"
  },
  "overrides": {  
    "loader-utils@>2.0.0 <3": "2.0.4",
    "loader-utils@>3.0.0 <4": "3.2.1"
  }
}
```

The pods failed at `npx ng serve` with the following error

```
ERROR: ld.so: object 'libnss_wrapper.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object 'libnss_wrapper.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object 'libnss_wrapper.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
npm info using npm@9.2.0
npm info using node@v18.9.1
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/npm 828ms (cache miss)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/npm 881ms (cache miss)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ng 1096ms (cache miss)
npm ERR! could not determine executable to run
```

I have tried every answer in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67833794/npm-err-could-not-determine-executable-to-run) and read [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/mvbzms/trouble_with_npx/). The solutions from the other stackoverflow post worked in the debug pod but when I add the step in the `scripts`. The pods failed with the same error in the next build again.

Things I have tried adding to the `scripts`:

```
"install": "npm install -g npm@9.2.0"
"prestart": "npm install -g"
```

Also tried put `npm` version in the `dependencies` and specified the `npm` version using `engines`. None worked for me.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the issue occurred because the `devdependencies` in the `package.json` was not installed. I have to pass an environment variable `NODE_DEV=development` for them to be installed which solved my issue. Thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34700610/npm-install-wont-install-devdependencies).

For future readers who encounter the same issue: If my solution does not work for you, please check if the other answers help with your situations.

Comment: Further to support my [answer](https://cloud.redhat.com/blog/getting-started-nodejs-oso3)

Answer (score 1):

You probably miss the `glibc` or `nss_wrapper-libs` package into your container. Some npm module require it to perform compilation during install (like couchbase module).

You could try to use a [multi-stage build dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/#name-your-build-stages) an have glibc only in the builder image, not the final one.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I had another look at my issue and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34700610/npm-install-wont-install-devdependencies) and I think it might have something to do with the `devdependencies` not being installed. I will give it a try and see if it works after installing the `devdependencies`.